AWS Elasticbeanstalk web application refused to connect
So hey all,
Starting my journey in Cloud so thought or doing a small project where I want to host my nextjs webapp on AWS using the Elasticbeanstalk
Now to do this i first dockerized the app then wrote a githubaction workflow to deploy the changes to my EBS on every commit to the main branch.
When i first created the EBS the sample application was working fine with the link
But as soon as I deployed my own app all I get is this screen.
enter image description here
heres the dockerfile:
FROM node:19-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .  
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000  

CMD ["npm", "start"]

The Github action:
name: Deploy to AWS
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"


jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Generate deployment package
        run: zip -r deploy.zip . -x '*.git*'

      - name: Deploy to EB
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v21
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          application_name: XCR
          environment_name: XCR-env
          version_label: ${{ github.sha }}
          existing_bucket_name: elasticbeanstalk-ap-south-1-211125526413
          region: ap-south-1
          deployment_package: deploy.zip

I created my own VPC with IGW & NAT gateways for public subnet.
enter image description here
Gave the Security group ALL TRAFFIC at every ip:
enter image description here
heres the instance network settings:
enter image description here
I tried to create a VPC with 192.168.0.0/24 subnets so that i can access the site but it failed

The security group rules you showed are for outbound rules. Did you also all incoming IP addresses?
